# WPF pool game-like slingshot interaction on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Good day everybody,

I have a touch-only application in which I would like to create a **slingshot interaction** that you could find, for instance, in a pool game. Something like Angry Birds, but without the physics of gravity, just inertia and deceleration.

To get a rough idea :

[image: Something like that, although I don't care about balls physics and hitting each other, I just want the slingshot interaction.]

For now, I have a BouncingUserControl inside a Canvas. The user should be able to do two things :

- **If he uses one touch point** : drag and drop the BouncingUserControl around, and throw it with a certain velocity. The BouncingUserControl, when released, will then bounce off the boundaries of the main window and stay inside said window.
- **If he uses a second touch point while dragging the BouncingUserControl**, a sort of elastic would appear : the further apart the two touch points are, the more tense the elastic would be. Upon releasing one of the two touch points, the BouncingUserControl would then be thrown with an initial velocity (that depends on how tense the "elastic" is) in the opposite direction.

Programmatically speaking, I have come this far :

This is my BouncingUserControl, a simple ellipse :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Slingshot.BouncingUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             ManipulationCompleted="ParentCanvasOnManipulationCompleted"
             ManipulationInertiaStarting="ParentCanvasOnManipulationInertiaStarting"
             ManipulationDelta="ParentCanvasOnManipulationDelta"
             ManipulationStarting="ParentCanvasOnManipulationStarting"
             >
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Beige"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Slingshot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour BouncingUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class BouncingUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public enum HorizontalEdgeBounceType
        {
            None,
            Left,
            Right
        }

        public enum VerticalEdgeBounceType
        {
            None,
            Top,
            Bottom
        }

        public BouncingUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private HorizontalEdgeBounceType CurrentHorizontalBounce { get; set; }

        private VerticalEdgeBounceType CurrentVerticalBounce { get; set; }


        public void ParentCanvasOnManipulationInertiaStarting(object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            ((MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this)).IsCurrentlyManipulating = false;
            ((MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this)).currentlyManipulatedControl = null;

            var element = args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //args.TranslationBehavior.DesiredDeceleration = 40.0 * 96.0 / (1000.0 * 1000.0);
            args.TranslationBehavior.DesiredDeceleration = 20.0 * 96.0 / (1000.0 * 1000.0);
            //args.TranslationBehavior.DesiredDeceleration = 0;
            args.Handled = true;
        }

        private void ParentCanvasOnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs manipulationCompletedEventArgs)
        {
            CurrentHorizontalBounce = HorizontalEdgeBounceType.None;
            CurrentVerticalBounce = VerticalEdgeBounceType.None;

        }

        private void ParentCanvasOnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            var element = args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

            if (element != null)
            {
                if (args.IsInertial)
                {
                    HandleHorizontalBounce(args);
                    HandleVerticalBounce(args);

                    args.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }

                var currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
                Canvas.SetLeft(this, currentLeft + args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X);

                var currentTop = Canvas.GetTop(this);
                Canvas.SetTop(this, currentTop + args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);

                args.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void ParentCanvasOnManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            args.ManipulationContainer = ParentCanvas;
            args.Handled = true;

            ((MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this)).IsCurrentlyManipulating = true;
            ((MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this)).currentlyManipulatedControl = this;

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentCanvasProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ParentCanvas", typeof(Canvas), typeof(BouncingUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Canvas)));

        public Canvas ParentCanvas
        {
            get { return (Canvas)GetValue(ParentCanvasProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentCanvasProperty, value); }
        }

        private void HandleVerticalBounce(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            var currentTop = Canvas.GetTop(this);

            //Update the current Vertical bounce if necessary
            if (currentTop < 0)
            {
                CurrentVerticalBounce = VerticalEdgeBounceType.Top;
            }
            else if (currentTop + ActualHeight >= ParentCanvas.ActualHeight)
            {
                CurrentVerticalBounce = VerticalEdgeBounceType.Bottom;
            }

            if (CurrentVerticalBounce != VerticalEdgeBounceType.None)
            {
                //Apply the new Translation taking into account we have bounced vertically
                switch (CurrentVerticalBounce)
                {
                    case VerticalEdgeBounceType.Top:
                        Canvas.SetTop(this, currentTop + Math.Abs(args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y));
                        break;
                    case VerticalEdgeBounceType.Bottom:
                        Canvas.SetTop(this, currentTop - Math.Abs(args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y));
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Just apply the Translation as normal
                Canvas.SetTop(this, currentTop + args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
            }
        }

        private void HandleHorizontalBounce(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs args)
        {
            var currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(this);

            //Update the current Horizontal bounce if necessary
            if (currentLeft < 0)
            {
                CurrentHorizontalBounce = HorizontalEdgeBounceType.Left;
            }
            else if (currentLeft + ActualWidth >= ParentCanvas.ActualWidth)
            {
                CurrentHorizontalBounce = HorizontalEdgeBounceType.Right;
            }

            if (CurrentHorizontalBounce != HorizontalEdgeBounceType.None)
            {
                //Apply the new Translation taking into account we have bounced horizontally
                switch (CurrentHorizontalBounce)
                {
                    case HorizontalEdgeBounceType.Left:
                        Canvas.SetLeft(this, currentLeft + Math.Abs(args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X));
                        break;
                    case HorizontalEdgeBounceType.Right:
                        Canvas.SetLeft(this, currentLeft - Math.Abs(args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X));
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Just apply the Translation as normal
                Canvas.SetLeft(this, currentLeft + args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The container of this BouncingUserControl is a simple canvas :

```
<Window x:Class="Slingshot.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Slingshot"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="#0a6c03" TouchDown="canvas_TouchDown" TouchMove="canvas_TouchMove" TouchUp="canvas_TouchUp">
            <local:BouncingUserControl  ParentCanvas="{Binding ElementName=canvas}" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" />
        </Canvas>
        <TextBlock x:Name="indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With this code-behind :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Slingshot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public BouncingUserControl currentlyManipulatedControl;
        public Boolean IsCurrentlyManipulating = false;
        Line slingshotAim;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeSlingShot();
        }

        private void InitializeSlingShot()
        {
            slingshotAim = new Line();
            slingshotAim.Stroke = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;

            slingshotAim.StrokeThickness = 3;
            canvas.Children.Add(slingshotAim);
            slingshotAim.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void canvas_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(canvas.TouchesOver.Count());

            if (IsCurrentlyManipulating && canvas.TouchesOver.Count() == 2)
            {
                slingshotAim.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                slingshotAim.X1 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(0).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.X;
                slingshotAim.Y1 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(0).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.Y;

                slingshotAim.X2 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(1).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.X;
                slingshotAim.Y2 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(1).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.Y;
            }
        }

        private void canvas_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsCurrentlyManipulating && canvas.TouchesOver.Count() == 2)
            {
                double slingshotLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((slingshotAim.X2-slingshotAim.X1),2)+Math.Pow((slingshotAim.Y2-slingshotAim.Y1),2));
                indicator.Text = slingshotLength.ToString();
                slingshotAim.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            }
        }

        private void canvas_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsCurrentlyManipulating && canvas.TouchesOver.Count() == 2)
            {
                double slingshotLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((slingshotAim.X2 - slingshotAim.X1), 2) + Math.Pow((slingshotAim.Y2 - slingshotAim.Y1), 2));
                indicator.Text = slingshotLength.ToString();

                slingshotAim.X1 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(0).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.X;
                slingshotAim.Y1 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(0).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.Y;

                slingshotAim.X2 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(1).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.X;
                slingshotAim.Y2 = canvas.TouchesOver.ElementAt(1).GetTouchPoint(canvas).Position.Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried raising an event where I would pass a ManipulationEventArgs, but there is no constructor for them. Another way of solving the problem would be to use animations on Canvas.TopProperty and Canvas.LeftProperty but that would prevent me from using the horizontal and vertical bounce, so I'd rather not do it that way.

Thanks for any kind of help or hint.